# WPF XAML Markup Compiler generates a bad URL in InitializeComponent()

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, msbuild

So I'm integrating WPF into a Windows Forms application I've built.  One of the big hurdles I'm running into is that when the Markup compiler generates the .g.cs files in the background, the InitializeComponent method is being generated incorrectly.

Here's what's generated:
System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/MapWorksheet;V9.9..0;component/controls/geoworksheetcon" +
                    "trol.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

What's incorrect is the version section of the URI descriptor.  This will work by either removing it or correcting the version (9.9.0.0 in this case).  I tried to change the version a bit to debug this (to 9.9.1.2), but this didn't affect the output of the tool.  I did delete the Obj directory first, so I know that this file was created fresh.

I'm looking for a way to correct this, currently I have to manually edit the .g.cs files to get this to work properly.

Oh, and I'm also using MSBuild and VS2008.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was an MSBuild configuration issue.

I worked this one out with my Build Engineer, he was overloading the AssemblyVersion property in MSBuild, which caused the XAML Compilation task to use a bad AssemblyVersion.

Answer (score 0):

To do so automatically:

```
<Target Name="SetBuildNumber">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="ItemsFromFile" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
        <In>@(ItemsFromFile)</In>
        <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
        <AssemblyVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</AssemblyVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="AssemblyVersion = $(AssemblyVersion)" Importance="high" />
</Target>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="SetBuildNumber" />
</Target>
```